# VB.NET GetElementById innertext

Tags: vb.net

Okay so this is my html line with the ID:

```
<id="accounttype" class=inline-block"><strong><?=$_SESSION['accounttype']?></strong><br>
```

this is what it grabs
of course though that turns into text

```
<?=$_SESSION['accounttype']?>
```

this is my vb.net code

```
  TextBox4.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("accounttype").InnerText
```

When i run the program i get this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an element with an ID of `accounttype`. All I see is an element with an ID of `newssite`. `GetElementById` returns the element who has an attribute `id` equal to whatever you pass it. For example:

```
<div id="accounttype">Hello World</div>
```

And the VB.NET Code:

```
TextBox4.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("accounttype").InnerText
```

You may not have included the code; but you should also make sure the WebBrowser has completely loaded its contents before trying to work with it.

Comment: Question the DIV is now making the <?=$_SESSION['accounttype']?> go under it  this is how it is now after div http://pastebin.com/jQB54Py5

Comment: Try changing the `div` to a `span`.

Answer (score 2):

**How to debug "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." errors**

If you have a statement of type

```
A.B = C.D.E.F
```

then this error can occur if `A` is Nothing, if `C` is Nothing, if `C.D` is Nothing or `C.D.E` is Nothing.

So, to debug this error, split up your statement like this:

```
Dim d = C.D
Dim e = d.E
Dim f = e.F
A.B = f
```

Now the line in which the error occurs will tell you *which* object was Nothing. Then check the documentation of the method call that created this object to find out under which circumstances this method call returns Nothing.

If, after doing so, you still don't understand why this happens, return to StackOverflow and post a new question, adding the information you have gained (for example: *Why does `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("accounttype")` return Nothing even though there is an element with ID `accounttype` in my document?*).