# Read the Name of an item on Website by Id

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm using the Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById command.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim Col As String = ""
    Try
        Col = wb1.Document.GetElementById("_arialId_118.row.cells.displayName").Name.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()))
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show(Col)

End Sub
```

I know that the ID is correct, because I checked it maually. However, i still get a NullReferenceException. What could be the cause of this?

EDIT: Document Example:

```html
<button type="button" class="_ph_I6 _ph_T6 o365button" tabindex="-1" role="group" id="_ariaId_118.row.cells"><div class="_ph_J6"> <div class="_ph_U6 _ph_R6">  </div> <div class="_ph_P6 _ph_R6 ms-font-color-neutralPrimary" tabindex="-1"> <span picturesize="50"> <span class="_ph_Q6 ms-font-weight-semilight PersonaPaneLauncher"><div class="_pe_d _pe_92 _pe_K _pe_i" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Persona-Karte" aria-haspopup="true">  <span class="_pe_j"> <div class="_pe_o2"> <span class="_pe_t _pe_R1 owaimg _pe_l2 _pe_q2 presenceJellyBeanBase presenceJellyBeanSmallBase presenceJellyBeanOffline" style=""> </span> </div> </span> <span class="_pe_n"> <div class="_pe_D1"><div style="display: none;"></div><div><div><div class="nonDraftPart _pe_12 _pe_j2 _pe_v2" style="background-size: cover; background-position: center center; background-color: rgb(43, 87, 151);">AA</div></div><div style="display: none;"></div></div></div> </span> <div style="display: none;"></div> </div></span> </span> </div> <span class="_ph_R6"> <span class="bidi _ph_S6 _ph_O6 disableTextSelection" tabindex="-1" role="button" id="_ariaId_119.row.cells.displayName" title="Abba Alessio">Abba Alessio</span> </span> <span class="_ph_R6"> <span class="bidi _ph_S6 _ph_O6 disableTextSelection" role="button" tabindex="-1" id="_ariaId_119.row.cells.emailAddress" title="Alessio_Abba@vs.sluz.ch">Alessio_Abba@vs.sluz.ch</span> </span> <span class="_ph_R6"> <span class="bidi _ph_S6 _ph_O6 disableTextSelection" role="button" tabindex="-1" id="_ariaId_119.row.cells.jobTitle" title="VSAD-Schüler">VSAD-Schüler</span> </span> <span class="_ph_R6"> <span class="bidi _ph_S6 _ph_O6 disableTextSelection" role="button" tabindex="-1" id="_ariaId_119.row.cells.officeLocation" title="VS">VS</span> </span> </div></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code instead:

```
Col = wb1.Document.GetElementById("_ariaId_119").Name.ToString ()
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't succeed. Why could an ID be 'Nothing'? This is what i'm curious about.

Comment: Can you provide the document sample? Just put it in your question.

Comment: @Cyrill Can you also make sure that you loaded the document correctly into the `wb1` variable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "document sample"?

Comment: @Cyrill Like you provide the ID you want to grab. For example: `<div id="accounttype">Hello World</div>`. Just like this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027217/vb-net-getelementbyid-innertext). By you providing the document, you are providing us enough information to help you out.

Comment: I mean the programm doesn't contain much more than what I already posted.

Comment: @Cyrill Can you show me the code where you initialize the `wb1` variable?

Comment: Ah yes of course, I added it.
 Here the wb1 variable (it's just a simple webbrowser) 
EDIT:  wrong one, is this what you mean?  Dim wb1 As New WebBrowser

Comment: @Cyrill Is it `_arialId_118.row.cells.displayName` or `_ariaId_119.row.cells.displayName`?

Comment: It doesn't matter. They are both ID's on that website.

Comment: @Cyrill Are you sure? From the document sample, I can't see `id=_ariaId_118.row.cells.displayName`. I can only see `id=_ariaId_119.row.cells.displayName`. Besides that, it is not `_arialId`. It is `_ariaId`

Comment: You are right. I just realized I made a terrible mistake. I corrected it. Sadly, the error message still shows up.

Comment: However, when I only used '_ariaId', (without. Row. Cells) it worked!

Comment: @Cyrill I have changed my answer to matches the ones worked for you. Is it the right one?